# jQuery Validation of email TLD vs. .Net 4.5 EmailAddressAttribute

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am currently using the [EmailAddressAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.EmailAddressAttribute%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) validation class on a string property in my view model. The problem I am running into is that on the client-side, jQuery validation allows for emails in the following format, "someDude@test" however when the view model is submitted, the ModelState fails because EmailAddressAttribute does not accept addresses in that format.

The only workaround I can think of is either applying a regex on the server side or create a custom jQuery validation rule.

Is there a cleaner fix to this?

Comment: Or you could create a new attribute that matches jQuery's requirements.

Comment: I would rather go for front-end valodation change as from what I know the example you give isn't valid...

Comment: @Bartdude, It is a valid email, see the demo on their site, http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

Comment: According to that site, this is the regex for emails provided by the jQuery Validation plugin: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_\`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/` (which it gets from the [HTML email input standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#e-mail-state-%28type=email%29))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up taking jwats1980 advice and creating a new custom validation attribute that agrees with the jQuery validation. Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SWCGPExternal.Attributes
{
    public class CustomEmailAddressAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return false;

            try
            {
                MailAddress m = new MailAddress((string)value);
                return true;
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            var clientValidationRule = new ModelClientValidationRule()
            {
                ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage,
                ValidationType = "email"
            };

            return new[] { clientValidationRule };
        }

    }
}
```